# Selenium - PhantomJS TypeError - undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()') string

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I create the auto application to a testing website in CSharp using Selenium and PhantomJS.

I have a problem when to try SendKeys("values") to the website.

```
<section id="login">
    <form class="login">
        <input type="text" id="login-username">
    </form>
</section>
```

It throws exception:

```
    Message "Unexpected error. TypeError - undefined is not a constructor 
   (evaluating '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()')" string
```

My code like:

`element.FindElementById("login-username").SendKeys("User1");`

I updated PhantomJS to the latest version.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I updated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

You should download PhantomJS 1.9.8 at [this link](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads). It will work in my case.

Phantom 2.1.1 or 2.0 don't work.

Comment: For me I'm still getting the same error in 1.9.8 as well as 2.1.1. I think it's something to do with phantomJS not working well with Knockout.

Comment: I created issues in the PhantomJS repositories on Github. And I hope this comment will help you. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14211#issuecomment-214983370